# Understanding string and list comparison for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand why this code I have written always displays true even tho  it should hit a false?

```
word = "the sky is blue"
checkList = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

for i in word.lower():
    if (i != checkList[0]) or (i != checkList[1]) or (i != checkList[2]) or (i != checkList[3]) or (i != checkList[4]):
    print("true")
else:
    continue
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to print true when there is a hit the checklist, use `==` not `!=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Python** `or` condition works in a particular way that if the first condition is true it will not check the other conditions but if the condition is `false`, it will check all the other conditions unless it finds the condition that is `true`. In your case you can do this:

```
word = "the sky is blue"
checkList = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

for i in word.lower():
    if i in checkList:
         print("true")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - is there somewhere I can better understand these operations?

Comment: There are many articles on it. This will be helpful to you. http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch04.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `and` instead of `or` would work, but better is:

```
for i in word.lower():
    if i not in checkList:
        print("true")
    else:
        continue
```

Or best is:

```
print('\n'.join(['true' for i in word.lower() if i not in checkList]))
```

Or if python3 (*Note: kinda inefficient, because i use list comprehension as an side-effect.*
):

```
print(*['true' for i in word.lower() if i not in checkList],sep='\n')
```

But if python 2, put `from __future__ import print_function`

Or the shortest:

```
[print('true') for i in word.lower() if i not in checkList]
```

Note in all examples, `checkList`, can be:

```
'aeiou'
```

Comment: I'm going to get some shut-eye so won't be trying it myself, but I think you could put `all` to some good use here too.

Comment: @usr2564301 hmmm... How?

Comment: isn't `[print('true') for i in word.lower() if i not in checkList]` bad practice as it would produce side-effects?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and` instead of `or`, beside, there are better ways to count characters. For instance, You can use `map`,

```
word = "the sky is blue"
chars = 'aeiou'

print(*map(lambda x : "{}:{}".format(x, word.lower().count(x)), chars))
# output,
a:0 e:2 i:1 o:0 u:1
```

Comment: Why `'s'` in `chars`?

Comment: removed it, it was a mistake @U9-Forward

Answer (score 0):

No string can possibly equal all of those different letters at once, so it will necessarily always be not-equal to most of them. Your `or`s should be `and`s to fix the problem, since you care that it's not equal to **any** of them, not that it's not equal to **all** of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the section

```
if (i != checkList[0])
```

every i included "in the sky is blue" is different from "a", so your condition is true everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "the sky is blue"
checkList = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
print [x not in checkList for x in word]

Result:[True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```